# Figuring out a conditional statement for a specific page

Tags: views

I have a view which is modified by a views template page - this is in Drupal 6.

I'm trying to figure out a condition to affect the layout. Currently, the  element seems to be generated in page.tpl.php, which is fine, but I want to add a condition for this specific page, in order to add an id to this element.

For other pages, I've used the node id to do this, as such:

```
else if ($node->nid == '250' || $node->nid == '429' || $node->nid == '555' || $node->nid == '378') {print '<h1'. ($tabs ? ' class="with-tabs"' : '') .' id="medspecheader">'. $title .'</h1>';}
```

But I'm not sure how to do this with the view page. Is there a machine name that I can use, or something to affect the layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to modify the default `page.tpl.php` to do something different when a specific path is called, you could just copy `page.tpl.php` to `page-PATH.tpl.php`, eg, `page-PATH-THAT-VIEWS-USES.tpl.php` and then anything inside this new template would be used just for the page displayed at that path.

In your example code, as an example, you could copy `page.tpl.php` to `page-node-250.tpl.php` or `page-node-429.tpl.php` etc and then you wouldn't need any `if`s in them with respect to the `id="medspecheader"` as these templates would only be used when looking at those nodes.

Just realize that the path used is the drupal system path, not any alias, but Views does create such a path for any Views that utilize a Page Display.

Lots more information about template suggestions for Drupal 6 can be found [here](https://drupal.org/node/1089642).

If these don't work for your specific needs, you can also create more templates suggestions for Drupal to use via a `hook_preprocess_page()` call in your module or theme.

For example, if you wanted the page to display differently whenever a specific node type is being displayed, and you didn't want to hard code in all of the specific node nids, you could do something like this in your theme...

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type=='med_special') {
    $variables['template_files'][]='page-cck-' . str_replace('_','-', $variables['node']->type);
  }

  // any other page preprocessing goes here

}
```

Now, whenever page displaying a node of type `med_special` is called up, Drupal will look for a `page-cck-med-special.tpl.php` file in your theme to display it.